# Installing Apache on other drive than C: gives error "could not determine server domain name"?

Tags: php, apache, server

I've installed `Apache` server in `D:` drive. I changed the paths in the `httpd.conf` file from `C:/Apache24` to `D:\Softwear\Apache\httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14\Apache24`. After that when I run the `httpd.exe` file in the console window, I get the following error:

> Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::b9d9:69d8:47f1:1406. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

The `ServerName` in the `httpd.conf` file seems valid. It is: 
`#ServerName www.example.com:80`

I doubt that the previous mentioned links had normal slash `/` as `c:/Apache24/htdocs` but now it is as `D:\Softwear\Apache\httpd-2.4.23-win64-VC14\Apache24/htdocs`

It containes both normal and inverted slashes. Another doubt is that in the `conf` folder ther is an `original` folder, which contains another `httpd.conf` file. Do I need to change paths in that file too?

Comment: A `#` means the line is commented out and ignored. Take out the `#`

Comment: @aynber I removed the hash `#` and then when I run `httpd.exe` nothing happened. The cursor has been blinking for one hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you have extracted Apache24 to drive D and you have changed `httpd.conf` from root C to D.

All you have to do then is open a Command Prompt, then change from C to D in your Apache folder, like this `D:\Apache24\bin`.

Then run `httpd -k install`, after success you can start it from Services windows Apache24 `Start`.